# "utils/uartstdio.h" gives unresolved symbols error when using with FreeRTOS

Tags: c, assembly, embedded

I am developing an application for **TM4C129** board using **Code Composer Studio**.
To print a string using UART I am using **UARTstudio library**.
Normally it works fine and doesn't give me any problem but when I try to use uartstudio with freeRTOS files, it gives me a linking error. I have tested it several times.
I have included the path as I do for non-FreeRtOS projects.

Here is the project configuration and hierarchy:[image]

Comment: Maybe you should inform the linker?

Comment: how to do that? plus it doesn't happen with every project. Only with those having FreeRTOS files.